# XMLPullParser not returnig correct AttributeCount value

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I am trying to parse some XML content using XMLPullParser in android, but I am stuck at one point.
Here is the XML code snippet:

```
<admin2 type="ABC" code="123" id="123">ABCD</admin2>
```

and here is my code:

```
 int eventType = parser.getEventType();
                    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                        String tagName=parser.getName();

                        switch (eventType){
                            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                                break;


                            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                                if(tagName.startsWith("admin")){
                                     //expected 3.. but I am getting as -1
                                     String ID=parser.getAttributeCount();
                                }
              }
```

I expect ID to have its values as 3 but I am getting it as -1. Rest of the code seems to be working fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public abstract int getAttributeCount ()
```

> Added in API level 1
>
> Returns the number of attributes of the current start tag, or -1 if the current event type is not START_TAG

Basically you might use this just within `START_TAG`. As you're using it within `END_TAG`, it's logical that you're receiving a -1 value.